# YUI animation running slow in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, yui, yui2

I have made an application using YUI-2 which uses different effects from YUI animation module. i have created a form works just like this: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/
In the application YAHOO.util.Scroll() is used to create animated effect.

```
var myAnim1 = new YAHOO.util.Scroll('container1', {
 left: {    
     to: 500
 } 
},1,YAHOO.util.Easing.easeOut);
myAnim1.animate();
```

The above code works perfect in Chrome but animation runs slow in Firfox and Internet Explorer.
Can anyone suggest me what could be the problem causing the code to run slow in these browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for slow animations is the speed of the browsers rendering engine.

Depending on what you are animating and how it affects the rendered part of the html page, the browser is forced to re-render the page for each step of the animation.

IE is usually very poor at this, firefox is usually fairly good, but has problems with some layouts. Chrome is nearly always very good at this and thus you rarely see problem there.

Comment: i have created 3 forms(with less than 3 fields each) and animated it like : http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/

Comment: Yes it looks like a re-rendering problem. Profiling the js shows very little activity and timeusage. (aroudn 3300 function calls and 43ms spent in firefox 3.6 on my machine when going through all the animation steps from account to confim)

Comment: Typically the more DOM elements you have the heavier it is to animate. The style of layout/css can also be a factor - absolutely positioned elements are easier to animate since they are easier to resolve by the render engine than dynamic width tables for instance. Floats are also fairly heavy, and stuff like collapsing margins.